# I can't display xml error message

Tags: xml

I can't display error message when given a wrong password or username. How can do this?

```
<div id="ErrorMessage" runat="server" align="center">
</div>


if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text))
{
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUser.Text, chkPersistLogin.Checked);
}
else
{
ErrorMessage.InnerHtml = "<b>Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatası...</b> Lütfen yeniden girin...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive. The property you are looking for is `innerHTML`, not `InnerHtml`.